# Как в ionic framework подключить chart.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Я использую sidemenu шаблон для своего приложения. В нем изначально создан модуль `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])`, но мне необходимо еще и подключить модуль `angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','chart.js'])`, чтобы обязательно было `chart.js` . Все это необходимо для создания контроллера графика.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы подключить модуль к `AngularJS`, сначала подтяните его html'ом, после загрузки `angular` и `ionic`

```
<script src="js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

потом измените свой код

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
```

на это

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'chart.js'])
```